# unable to use static resource method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

unable to use static resource code in JS

**StResource.js**

```
function multiplyMe(a,b) {
    return a*b;
}
function AddMe(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

**MyComp.cmp**

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.StResource}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptLoad}" />
```

**MyCompController.js**

```
scriptLoad : function(cmp) {
     multiplyMe(10,20);
}
```

getting error

> [multiplyMe is not defined]

after using given [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/static-resource-in-lighting-component/136762#136762) it gives me **lightning cli error**

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/136762/20830) this will help you out.

Comment: i'm using above given answer but it gives me lightning cli error.

Comment: If you are getting an error message, please post it verbatim (in its entirety).

Comment: @AshwaniKumar Look at this [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/137376/20830). The scope of CLI to scan to through static resource is limited at the moment. So we are fine here.